# Drift in output voltage of load cell

Tags: load-cell

I used [one of these scales](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01LYKG1CM/) and after a few months the reading started drifting up: after hitting tare to get to zero, the reading would show 2 grams, then slowly go up to 10 g in one minute.

I thought the problem was in the electronic circuit so I took it apart, hooked the load cell to an amplifier and a microcontroller, and got the same results: after an initial calibration to a known weight of 200g, the reading increases from 200g to 269.7g in 30 minutes, removing the 200g weight brings the reading down to 89.7g, and adding the 200g weight again brings the reading to 348.8g.

A drift in the measurement has to come from a drift in the resistance of the load cell. [This page](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/load-cell-offset-drift-cancellation-circuit.111837/) mentions offset drift:

> I've been working with load cells for a long time now, and one of the problems that I have not yet been able to solve to my satisfaction is offset drift. Offset drift is the drift in output voltage over time even when the cell is under no load.

But I have had many commercial scales that show no similarly strong drift.

What could explain such a strong drift?

**Update**: I left running for 5 hours, where the only difference was that a soldered connection from the HX711 to the load cell broke and I replaced with an alligator cable. Instead of a strong drift, I now have a negative drift and then a positive one:

[image: Plot of scale output at rest]

Comment: "Creep" is an effect that affects load cells to one degree or another. For $12 retail price, perhaps it's not of the finest of materials or construction.

Comment: I read about creep [from SparkFun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/openscale-applications-and-hookup-guide#calibration-suggestions) and it would explain a restart in drift as soon as the weight changes. If so, the creep has considerable magnitude. Do you have an idea how to test if it's creep?

Comment: I would power the load cell with a stable reference voltage, read the output with a 6-1/2 digit voltmeter and record the results. Creep has a logarithmic characteristic, so the rate of change drops but never completely stops.

Comment: Can creep invert between positive and negative? I recorded 5 hours at rest and got the graph with an inversion and updated question.

Comment: If you're still using the built-in amplifier, it's quite likely a good part of what  you are seeing is thermal drift, possibly much of it from the amplifier. There's no reason for them to use a good amplifier (low TCVos = temperature coefficient of offset voltage) since it's typically zeroed digitally right before each reading. In case it wasn't clear, I suggested reading the load cell output directly. Zero-drift amplifier ICs would be appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks! I am using my own HX711 amplifier but I couldn't find if it's zero-drift. I used a multimeter to confirm that input voltage from the circuit is stable at 3.28V. With a 200mV setting in the multimeter, output voltage hovers around zero, positive and negative, with no clear difference with or without weight on the load cell. Am I doing something wrong or do I just need more precision in my measurement?

Comment: If you can short the input of the amplifier you can isolate some of its behavior from the load cell.

Comment: My problem was measuring with the multimeter on the amplifier's pins, which was unstable. Now I unsoldered and added header pins and alligator cable and the result is stable and seems reliable with instant measurements and 0.1 V precision, either with or without input shorting on the amplifier. I will leave the drift running for 24 hours and report again tomorrow.